# WPF Binding RelativeSource to Ancestor Issue

Tags: wpf, data-binding, relativesource

I'm binding a collection of collections to a WPF datagrid component(external library) and the underlying `DataSource` has the following structure. This basically gives me a datagrid with hierarchical records

```
class DataGridItemType
{
    public string weightType;
    public string SourceType;
    private BindingList<DataGridItem> typeCollection = new BindingList<DataGridItem>();
}


BindingList<DataGridItemType> list = new BindingList<DataGridItemType>();
```

`list` is the datagrids DataSource and this performs hierarchical binding. Now, I tried binding a component(The header label of the records one level into the hierarchy whose datasource is typeCollection) to the variable `weightType` by using, `Text="{Binding Path=weightType, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type btm:DataGridItemType}}}` but the binding doesn't work. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

AncestorType should be the UI Element in the UI hierarchy whose DataContext (which would be an object of DataGridItemType - your custom class) you want to bind to.

There is no code snippet here but read the remarks section [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743599.aspx)

Comment: how do I bind to a variable from there? Do I set `Path = DataContext.weightType` ?

Comment: @Aks - try it and let me know if it doesn't work. However since DataContext is inherited unless you specify an explicit DataContext at the child level, you may not need all this. You could just use `{Binding Path=weightType}` without the RelativeSource

Comment: It wont work.Can I debug and see if it is able to find the ancestor?